# Create a new column based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my dataframe:

```
      ID  Tell  Number Animals
0       1   Yes     3    Cat
1       1   Yes     6    Pig
2       1   No      9    Dog
3       2   Yes     4    Cat
4       2   Yes     7    Pig 
5       2   No      8    Dog
6       3   Yes     15   Cat
7       3   Yes     8    Pic 
8       3   Yes      6   Dog
9       3   Yes     13   Cat
```

I want to add a 5th column that checks for each ID if there is a row that has 'No' in the Tell column. If it does, then the 5th column is the corresponding number for the corresponding ID. If there are no row's with 'No', then leave it blank.

So, my resultant df should look like this:

```
      ID  Tell  Number Animals col5
0       1   Yes     3    Cat    9
1       1   Yes     6    Pig    9
2       1   No      9    Dog    9
3       2   Yes     4    Cat    8
4       2   Yes     7    Pig    8
5       2   No      8    Dog    8
6       3   Yes     15   Cat    
7       3   Yes     8    Pic 
8       3   Yes     6    Dog
9       3   Yes     13   Cat
```

Here is what I started with:

```
df.loc[df['Tell'].str.contains('No'), 'col5'] = df['Number']
```

Please help

Comment: you actually can't leave blank things in series. it should be empty string, nan or zero.. or something else.

Answer (score 1):

We can do filter then `merge`

```
s=df.loc[df.Tell.eq('No'),['ID','Number']].rename(columns={'Number':'Col5'})
df=df.merge(s,on='ID',how='left')
df
   ID Tell  Number Animals  col5  Col5
0   1  Yes       3     Cat   9.0   9.0
1   1  Yes       6     Pig   9.0   9.0
2   1   No       9     Dog   9.0   9.0
3   2  Yes       4     Cat   8.0   8.0
4   2  Yes       7     Pig   8.0   8.0
5   2   No       8     Dog   8.0   8.0
6   3  Yes      15     Cat   NaN   NaN
7   3  Yes       8     Pic   NaN   NaN
8   3  Yes       6     Dog   NaN   NaN
9   3  Yes      13     Cat   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: How did you create the dataframe for your testing from OP's data? Manually?